# SWIG C++ to Python: generate a subclass of Python list

Tags: python, c++, subclass, swig

I am using SWIG (v3) to wrap C++ code to Python 3. In C++, I have a class `MyClass` which inherits from `std::vector`. I want to wrap this in Python, such that the resulting Python class `MyClass` is a subclass of the standard Python `list` class. Is this possible?

Here is an example:

**example.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// List class
class MyList : public vector<int> 
{
    public:
        // Init
        MyList() : vector<int>() {
            this->insert(this->begin(),2);
            this->insert(this->begin(),1);
        }

        // Toy insert function
        void toy_insert() 
        {
            this->insert(this->begin(),0);
        }
};
```

**example.cpp**

```
#include "example.h"
```

**example.i**

```
%module example

%{
     #include "example.h"
%}

%include "std_vector.i"

using namespace std;

%template(MyVector) std::vector<int>; // Nothing known about base class 'vector< int >' if we remove std:: here

%typemap(out) MyList* {
  int size = (*$1).size();
  $result = PyList_New(size);

  for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
    PyList_SetItem($result, i, PyInt_FromLong((*$1)[i]));
  }
};

// List class
class MyList : public std::vector<int> // Nothing known about base class 'vector< int >' if we remove std:: here
{
  public:
    MyList();
    void toy_insert();
};
```

**run_example.py**

```
import example

my_list = example.MyList()
print(my_list)
```

The print command returns `<example.MyList; proxy of [1, 2] >`, but this is not what I want. Ideally this should just return `[1,2]`, but then I would still be able to call:

```
my_list.toy_insert()
print(my_list)
```

which should return `[0,1,2]`.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If your example returned `[1,2]` as you would like, it would be a Python list and not have a `.toy_insert()` method.  You could override `__str__` and/or `__repr__` and make it *display* `[1,2]` instead of the default `<example.MyList; proxy of [1,2]>`.  Then it would still be a wrapped object and you could still call `.toy_insert()`.  BTW, using a `using` in a header is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is not really possible. This looks like a list to the user, but of course doesn't magically inherit the methods of the Python `list` class - it seems there is no easy way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you can override the display of a SWIG type.  Here's a rough example:

```
%module x

%{
#include "example.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>
%include <std_vector.i>

%template(MyVector) std::vector<int>;

%include "example.h"

%extend MyList {

const char*__repr__()
{
    // I was lazy.
    return "fancy representation";
}

}
```

Output:

```
>>> import x
>>> t=x.MyList()
>>> t
fancy representation
>>> t[0]
1
>>> t[1]
2
>>> t.toy_insert()
>>> t[0]
0
>>> t[1]
1
>>> t[2]
2
```